# how to import a dataframe with character lines between values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a brief description of software and lines between values
like this

> Model: LI-1500 Light Sensor Logger 
>   Config: SALIDA
>   Session Remark:
>   Software Version:   1.0.0
>
> v1 v2 v3
>   30    55 55
>
> 10 20 50
>   Model: LI-1500 Light Sensor Logger 
>   Config: SALIDA
>   Session Remark:
>   Software Version:   1.0.0

I can remove the first description using the arg skip in the read.table function however I haven't could find the way of remove the text between the values of dataframe

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: please make your example reproducible (use `dput`)

Comment: What are "lines between values"? What is the expected result?